How to update a custom field in cart using PHP in WooCommerce?
I am using WordPress & WooCommerce & some plugin for travel agencies. The Products are tours.
So each product is a combo of standard fields of WooCommerce + some custom fields coming from a plugin. But the functionality is a bit weak, so I am extending it using custom code, because I need a feature, which is not implemented yet.
My problem is that in the cart each tour has tickets, either adult or child (Product X -> Tickets -> Adult Y Tickets, Child Z tickets). A bunch of tickets is one product.
I have successfully added my own JavaScript code to update them on the front-end, like in this link.
Here is a screenshot

So I am thinking to add Ajax endpoints in WP, where the PHP code implements the same changes in the database, as the JavaScript code already do.
I tried the following to fix changes:
 WC()->cart->cart_contents[$cart_item_key]['ttbm_ticket_info'][0]['ticket_qty'] = $value;

but it seems to be wrong, and doesn't work.
I need advice, what is the right way to update cart item custom fields, so the changes appear permanently in the database, not only in temporary during the PHP execution in server RAM.
The attempts are described in the main post.

Try to provide in your question, all the related code used, not just a line of code… Note that "your question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem."  Also, your question is unclear: What additional plugins are you using? How is that product custom data implemented on the cart item?

RESOLVED.
I just forgot about WC()->cart->set_session();
Now small step is done to the final solution, heh ...
